# Use appsettings to drive environment specific settings such as UseUrls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi

When I'm developing locally using VS Code, I'm going to use port 3000 because I'm a hipster. The non-hipsters want it on port 8080 on the server. That's cool, we got this. Microsoft docs give me the following example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .Configure(app =>
        {
            app.Run(async (context) => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hi!"));
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

I don't want to use `hosting.json`. Why would I want that? I have this `appsettings.{environment}.json` file for exactly this situation. Sweet, I'll just paste that bad boy in

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();
```

What the compiler error? `env` does not exist in the current context. It only exists in the `Startup.cs` file--which is not called on startup, but called *from* the startup file, `Program.cs`, with sorcery.

So, how do I solve this problem? How can I store my environment-specific hosting settings in my environment-specific `appsettings.json`, and subsequently use it in while building my environment-specific web host via the `WebHostBuilder` in `Program.cs`?

Comment: you could use launchSettings.json to drive this.

Comment: using vscode, but would like a ide-agnostic solution in either case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible.  Expanding on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37468237/272069), by creating the WebHostBuilder and ConfigurationBuilder in the Program.cs, it is possible to have access to the host environment and then configure the host URL and port in environment-specific appsettings files.

Assuming an appsettings.json and an apppsettings.Development.json file each with the following:

```
"hostUrl": "http://*:<port number here>"
```

Modify the Main with the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder();
    var env = host.GetSetting("environment");
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    var configuration = builder.Build();

    host.UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls(configuration["hostUrl"])
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

Using this code, the Startup.cs will still need to declare its own ConfigurationBuilder in order to publicly expose its Configuration property.

Comment: `env` always return Development

Answer (score 0):

Or, starting from .NET Core 2.0, when creating the default `IWebHostBuilder` that will build the `IWebHost` implementation, you can use

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
                // nb: here you may clear configuration(s) loaded so far
                var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: But how do you access `config` in UseUrls ?

Comment: in .net core 2 you can set the listening port in the kestral settings like so:     
                     
    .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
    {
        var port = context.Configuration.GetSection("port").Value;
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(port));
    })