# IdentityServer4 : how to set Authority based on environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

All the IdentityServer4 examples hardcode the `Authority` property during configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.ApiName = "api";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Env.IsStaging() || Env.IsProduction();
            });
```

How would I load the Authority based on environment (i.e. staging and production)?

Comment: Are not Env.IsStaging() and Env.IsProduction() enough in this case?

Comment: @DanNguyen I don't want to hardcode the urls based on booleans inline. I think they should be loaded via some configuration file or environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what we do:

We have different `appSettings.json` files for each Environment.

[image]

All files contain separate values for IdentityServer. e.g.

```
{
  "IdentityServerSettings": {
    "Authority": "http://localhost:5000",
    "ApiName": "tb5api"
  }
}
```

Then in the Startup.cs class we load the settings json file based on current environment.

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }


public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
      .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<IdentityServerSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerSettings"));
......
```

Then we have an class to load our settings into:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// This class is a representation of the configuration of the API for Identity Server
    /// </summary>
    public class IdentityServerSettings
    {
        // Authority is the Identity Server URL
        public string Authority { get; set; }

        // Current API/Resource Name
        public string ApiName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then wherever you need the `IdentityServerSettings` you can inject them in the controller OR in the Configure Method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();



            #region Identity Server Config
            var identityServerOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<IdentityServerSettings>>().Value;

            // Setup Identity Server Options for this API - 
            app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = identityServerOptions.Authority,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ApiName = identityServerOptions.ApiName,
                NameClaimType = "username",
            });

.......
```

Comment: If you load the host from appsettings.json how do you set them in program.cs when configuring the webhost? From your code it looks like you are setting the authority manually from appsettings.json but you are just using the default host when configuring the webhost.

Comment: @Bob webhost of the Identity server or the Client website?

Comment: @Bob I think this is what you are looking for to set the settings in the Program Startup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265773/1910735

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for.